# Marker clusterer + overlapping markers gmap v3

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-markers, markerclusterer

I know that this topic is common, but i cant figure how to solve my problem.

I'm using gmap v3 and markercluster, sometime i have markers in the same position(lat/lng).
I know that google doesnt provide any solutions for that, but i'd like to open an infowindow containing the points when the markers are overlapped.

Anybody knows how can i do it?
Thankss